# Installing libhoudini (ARM emulation) on Android 4.2.2. Emulator

Tags: android, unix, android-emulator, filesystems

After about 3 days trying and trying I'm giving up.

I've tried to install libhoudini (http://android-x86.sceners.org/en/?p=536) on android 4.2.2 emulator. I need that for a project.

I know about the existence of Genymotion and AndroVM but I don't need a virtual box image I need a emulator running on intel x86 with ARM emulation.

I also tried to create yaffs2 images from a running Genymotion distrubition and migrate that to android-sdk\system-images\android-17\x86. Unfortunately that doesn't work.

So I hope that someone can help me out and/or point me in the right direction. So what I need: a rebuilt of system-images\android-17 folder content with a rooted device and libhoudini installed.

I don't know if SO is the place for this questions but I'm willing to pay someone to create this for me because it's very important for a commercial project.

Update 14-10: Still not a step further. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, do you have an update for this topic? I'm studying the same issue with you. What I have tried is modify the x86 emulator image following enable_houdini from Android-x86. So far I'm able to install an arm-only Apk. But it failed during start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I don't know why you have something against Genymotion but you can try using the Flashable ZIP I made for setting up libhoudini in Genymotion v2.0. It works there but I have no idea how good your mileage will be with using it for a Android-x86 install. It might depend on what kernel is being used. It's just a normal Flashable ZIP so you can use whatever recovery method you have, or manually copy each file to their correct folders and set their permissions. You can find the download on my XDA guide:

[[GUIDE] Genymotion | Installing ARM Translation and GApps - XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952)