# Android 4.2 ndk: library loading crash: load_library(linker.cpp:750) || soinfo_link_image || libhoudini.so || opencv

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am using a native library that includes opencv.
The library builds well and works well in all devices and emulators, but not on Android 4.2 ones. It crashes on `System.loadLibrary("mylib");`.

The library is built for armeabi-v7a armeabi x86 mips (I see in the jnilibs folder that all the so files were generated)

I am stuck on this bug because I couldn't find any answer on the internet which could explain my problem.

`Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libopencv_java.so"`, log trace:

```
1755-1755/com.ex.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libopencv_java.so" needed by "libmylib.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "libopencv_java.so" not found
           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:371)
           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
           at com.ex.app.core.MyApplication.initVippAsync(MyApplication.java:198)
           at com.ex.app.core.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:100)
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1000)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4391)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include /Users/ahmed/Documents/openCv4android/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_MODULE    := mylib
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ldl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := myFile.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a armeabi x86 mips
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
```

Comment: On what kind of devices did you try? Did you check if the missing files stated in the error message are presents in the device? Some reading for libhoudini: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/11/21/libhoudini-what-it-means-for-developers.html, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945181/installing-libhoudini-arm-emulation-on-android-4-2-2-emulator

Comment: 100% reproducible on any device 4.2. I had it on genymotion emulator and in a DOOGEE device that has Android 4.2. For the other devices and emulators it works as expected.

Comment: I have seen the link that you sent me, it says that libhoudini will be used on x86 platforms to convert arm binaries to x86 binaries, if I didn't provide x86 binaries. But I did, so it should not even call houdini.

Comment: What are your build files?

Comment: @DanAlbert: I have just updated my question.

Comment: Try explicitly loading the opencv library from java before you load your own library (doesn't matter if it has no jni methods inside).  It might work, and even if it doesn't it will probably give you a more specific error message as to why it hasn't loaded.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found my answer. It's two steps:

1/ If you're using an emulator Genymotion, with an Android 4.2.2, you will have a missing library, caused by one of the updates of Genimotion. See [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952). 
Solution : 
(1)> download the following zip file: [here](http://filetrip.net/dl?nyIEf5nUK7).
(2)> simply drag and drop it to your emulator.
(3)> restart your emulator.

2/ In the Android 4.2 the OS has problems to find paths to jni libraries shipped in the apk. For example in my case, I am using a jni library that uses the openCV library. 
For every device and android version calling `System.loadLibrary("mylib");` worked well and `mylib` loaded automatically the opencv library. 
For the Android 4.2, as @Chris said in his comment, I loaded openCV explicitly, so :

```
System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");
System.loadLibrary("mylib");
```

Comment: Where did you added these two lines?!

Comment: in place of System.loadLibrary("mylib");

Comment: I don't get it! I means where should i type these line?! activity?class? Is it limited that we should only use it in a class?

Comment: where are you're loading your library? If you don't have any native library to load this question and answer has nothing to do with your question. Now, if yes you have a library that you're building with ndk (i.e my_lib) and you need to load it somewhere (in a class or activity. in my case in the application class), the usual way to do it is  `System.loadLibrary("mylib");` . Now if you're using openCV by your native library, you need to use this answer to fix a kitkat issue.

Comment: i added it when app loaded attachBaseContext() and it worked for me