# Playscape Native Android Demo - library "libgnustl_shared.so" not found

Tags: android, playscape

I have build the Demo project as described in Playscape Documentation. Modified only the API Key and icon to ic_launcher in manifest.

*** UPDATED DETAILS ***

Error on Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 w Android 4.4.2:

```
10-12 17:01:40.979: A/libc(18565): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00004885 (code=-6), thread 18565 (e.publishingkit)
```

Error on Huawei G700 w Android 4.2.1:

```
10-12 01:00:56.875: E/dalvikvm(15680): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.playscape.publishingkit-1/libplayscape_pubkit.so") failed: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libgnustl_shared.so" needed by "libplayscape_pubkit.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "libgnustl_shared.so" not found
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libgnustl_shared.so" needed by "libplayscape_pubkit.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "libgnustl_shared.so" not found
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:514)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at com.playscape.api.report.Report.(Report.java:19)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at com.playscape.publishingkit.PlayscapeDemoActivity.reportLevelStarted(PlayscapeDemoActivity.java:151)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at com.playscape.publishingkit.PlayscapeDemoActivity.executeAPIMethod(PlayscapeDemoActivity.java:72)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at com.playscape.publishingkit.PlayscapeDemoActivity.access$0(PlayscapeDemoActivity.java:64)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at com.playscape.publishingkit.PlayscapeDemoActivity$1.onItemClick(PlayscapeDemoActivity.java:58)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1128)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2812)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3571)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:929)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
10-12 01:00:56.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

- Playscape SDK 1.15
- Android SDK 6.0
- JRE 1.8.0_60
- Eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)

Comment: Hi Ghelle. Looks like you have the same problem described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28817942/3865127).

Comment: Thanks @Artem. I checked on Android 4.4.2 and it crashes on it also, but error is different.